# Click Listener of button from the XML of a fragment that is MVVM based architecture not working

Tags: java, android, mvvm, fragment

Don't Know why my logout button is not working from the XML via data-binding.

> ProfileFragment.java

This is simply the fragment for viewing the profile.

```
 public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;
private FragmentProfileBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    profileViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ProfileViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    //        binding.btnLogout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    ////            logout(v); from here it works but I want to perform this from XML
    //        });
    profileViewModel.getModelLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new 
    Observer<UserModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(UserModel profileViewModel) {
            binding.username.setText(profileViewModel.getUsername());
            binding.email.setText(profileViewModel.getEmail());
            binding.phone.setText(profileViewModel.getPhone());
            binding.cnic.setText(profileViewModel.getCnic());
            binding.adress.setText(profileViewModel.getAdress());
        }
    });
    return root;
}

public void logout(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "logout clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
}
```

> ProfileViewModel.java

**Profile View model is previously populated then make the XML to view that text**

```
public class ProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {

public MutableLiveData<String> username = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> email = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> cnic = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> password = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> phone = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> adress = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<String> img = new MutableLiveData<>();

private MutableLiveData<UserModel> userMutableLiveData;

public MutableLiveData<UserModel> getModelLiveData() {

    if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
        userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return userMutableLiveData;
}

public ProfileViewModel() {
    UserModel userModel = UserAfterLogin.getUserModel();
    getModelLiveData().setValue(userModel);

}

//the following method needs to be in working with the fragment xml click listener
//    android:onClick="@{(v) -> ProfileFragment.logout(v)}"
public void logout(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

> fragment_profile.xml

**The XML of my fragments in which the main issue occurs.**

**android:onClick="@{(v) -> ProfileFragment.logout(v)}"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="ProfileFragment"
        type="com.fyp.utilitymoan.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:text="@={ProfileFragment.username}"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:text="@={ProfileFragment.email}"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cnic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="CNIC"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@={ProfileFragment.cnic}"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@={ProfileFragment.phone}"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:text="@={ProfileFragment.adress}"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> ProfileFragment.logout(v)}"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: my edit text is populated with the data binding exactly the right way I want but my logout button and second button are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call viewmodel method from xml using data binding ,first you need to set viewmodel object for xml in your fragment.

```
profileViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
    binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    binding.setProfileFragment(profileViewModel);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also @Ammar you should not need your `onChange` function - once you have the binding set up correctly, those fields should update automatically from the XML bindings.

Comment: ***binding.setProfileFragment(profileViewModel);***
So this is the only line I'm missing. Thanks for figuring it out

Comment: This saved me, else I will shift MVVM to simple Architecture.

Comment: @dominicoder can u please elaborate a little on what's basically is it binding.setProfileFragment(profileViewModel)

Comment: Nothing @Ammar ,in java class file we need to import all dependency to make it work like that android xml file is just layout  file it doesn't know anything except view,if we need simple pojo class or viewmodel class in xml ,we need to set that dependency (for better understanding) using data binding.

Comment: data binding creates id for view to set the data for view like binding.username.setText()  like that creates id for classes within data tag to set value.if variable name inside <variable> tag is MyViewModel ,databinding creates setMyViewModel to set that variable.if it is myPojo ,databinding creates setMyPojo .@Ammar

Comment: so the fragment or any other XML needs the `binding.setModel(model_class)` which we are using inside our XML like that : `<layout><data><variable /></data></layout>`  **But** @androidLearner when I'm not using this( `binding.setModel(model_class)`) my data from the model class also set on the XML and just the btns click listners not working,why?